# JavaScript finds HTML text that is not present

Tags: javascript, html

Simple question - Why does my log "find" test in my HTML page? It does not exist.

Any ideas?

Thanks all!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script></script>
    <script>
       if(document.body.innerHTML.search("test") || 
          document.documentElement.textContent || 
          document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf('test') > -1 ) 
       {
            console.log("found");
       }
       else
       {
           console.log("not found");
       } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.documentElement.textContent` is truthy

Comment: does it need the parameter of the search text past in? no, right? It's a property

Comment: You have a `||` logical operator there, so when the first one fails it moves on to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have `|| document.documentElement.textContent` this will always be `true` you will need to change your code to be something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>This is some more text</p>
    <script></script>
    <script>
       if (document.body.innerText.includes('test')) {
          console.log('found');
       } else {
          console.log('not found');
       }      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the second part of the test returns all the content within the document as an HTML string (making it truth-y).

```
document.documentElement.textContent
```